# How to access to element in an array generate by findAll

Tags: php, arrays, doctrine, findall

I have  to test if my current users exists in other table or not?
how to access to getId in the userOldList   list: the following code produce an erro :HTTP ERROR 500

```
$user = new User();
$repositoryUserOld= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(userOld::class);
$userOldList   = $repositoryUserOld->findAll();

$form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
$form->handleRequest($request);
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    foreach ($userOldlList as $userO ) {

        If ($user->getId() == $userO->getId() )
       {
           $form->get('id')->addError(new FormError('User exists'));
           return $this->render('AppBundle:MyApp:user.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
       }
   }
```

Comment: Can you debug and mark on your code on which line its breaks? Can you split the `if` to `$u1 = $userO->getId()` and `$u2 = $userO->getId()` to verify where it breaks?

Comment: I feel like this is way long method to do very minute stuff. `Check if posted user data may be email already exists in table`, this may be main question. Is it @Julie?

Answer (score 0):

In `foreach` you are using variable `$userOldlList` (note `l` between `Old` and `List`), but at the top you define variable `$userOldList`. I think that's why you get error 500.

As for the how to do that more efficiently, this could can replace whole `foreach` block (only condition in `if` is a new code; inner block is a copy from your question without any changes):

```php
if ($repositoryUserOld->find($user->getId()) {
    $form->get('id')->addError(new FormError('User exists'));
    return $this->render('AppBundle:MyApp:user.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

BTW, originally I just copy-pasted your code into a new file in PhpStorm, and it highlighted misspelled variable right away. Having a tool that checks your code as you type it is a great way to improve your productivity.